# Custom section border/background in a UITableViewStyleGrouped TableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

can you remove section background and border of a particular seciton in a UITableViewStyleGrouped TableView?

Comment: Not sure of what you need. Maybe you need to access `cell.backgroundView` or `cell.backgroundColor` in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method. (cell is defined as `UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`)

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the background using the table view's `backgroundColor` and `backgroundView` properties. You can also change the `borderColor` and `borderStyle` properties.